# Failure to boot after rooting LG Optimus V and installing CM7

Tags: rooting, cyanogenmod, lg-optimus-one

I recently bought an LG Optimus V (VirginMobile) to replace my current Samsung Intercept. Upon reciept, I rooted it following the procedure at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1070018. The rooting went fine, and I got to step 10 in flashing the CM7 Rom. What I get after the reboot specified in step 9 is the CyanogenMod animated splashscreen, which animates for a bit, then stops, and thats where the unit stays, for up to an hour. I can get to the installed recovery console, but have no idea what I need to do to fix this. I rooted this unit immediately after getas the main reason for needing a smartphone is the fact I need to have OpenVPN installed on any phone I have. I went crazy getting my previous Samsung Intercept rooted and then getting the tun.ko for the installed kernel. The final fix was to install a 3rd party rom which supplied the kernel module. I did not want to go thru that again on this LG phone. Whats my next step?

Comment: Those directions instruct you to wipe the `/cache` partition from recovery before installation but not `/data`. I would try that (if you have not already), since leftover files on the `/data` partition are a common cause of boot problems when going from one ROM to another. Note, this is basically a factory reset. It will erase your installed apps, accounts, settings, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments in the other answer(s) state, make sure to wipe both the `/cache` and `/data` partitions.

I failed to do this and my Cyanogenmod 7.2 ROM hung on boot. When I wiped both partitions (via the ClockworkMod Recovery console), the phone booted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is although you have reset your phone, somehow it can't find a partition to boot from.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. It's entirely possible to bootloop (i.e. hang at the boot splash) even if you have a perfectly valid partition setup, which is why a data wipe is generally recommended when switching ROMs.

Comment: ahh.. figured it was something like that.. I'm an old-hand on Linux, but very new on Android.. I'm pretty sure I wiped the /cache and /data via recovery but I'll try it again..